# How to disable the dynamic transparency effect of the dock while maximizing a window?

Tags: 17.10, panel, gnome-shell, dock, ubuntu-dock

How to disable this effect?
Check the panel and dock's transparency on Ubuntu 17.10.
Difference between the panel's transparency before and after maximizing any windows:

- Before maximizing a window (which I like):

  [image: Before maximizing]
- After maximizing the window (which I don't like when it happens):

  [image: After maximizing]

I don't want that effect after maximizing a window.
Is it possible to make change to the gnome's panel like Xfce's panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Transparency of Ubuntu Dock

Open Terminal and run the following command first to allow custom alpha values for Ubuntu dock

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock customize-alphas true
```

Then run the following command to obtain the alpha value of the dock as in the first screenshot

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock min-alpha
```

The output is say `0.2`.

Finally run the following to set the maximum alpha value (i.e. when a window is maximised)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock max-alpha 0.2
```

Then log out and log in again.

#### Transparency of the top bar

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Dynamic Panel Transparency](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1011/dynamic-panel-transparency/) to achieve fixed transparency of the top bar.

1. Install the extension from the link above.
2. Reload the page. A settings icon should appear.
3. Click on the settings icon. A window should pop up.
4. Go to the "*Background*" tab and toggle on "Enable custom opacity".
5. Set low values (say 30% or 40%) for both "Maximized Opacity" and "Unmaximized Opacity".
   [image]
6. Log out and log in again.

Comment: My output is 0.20000000000000001 for this command: `gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock min-alpha`   ...so i should type this?:  `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock max-alpha 0.20000000000000001`? or `0.2`?

Comment: @Sss Yes, you can set any value between 0 (completely transparent) and 1 (completely opaque). For the sake of consistency it's better to keep `min-alpha` and `max-alpha` same.