# Ubuntu MATE: How do I disable transparency of the titlebar of the active window?

Tags: compiz, mate, ubuntu-mate

I've set Compiz as my window manager since all the other options were causing screen tearing.  The problem is that this causes the title bar of the active window (even if fullscreen) to be completely transparent (but only in some themes), which I find incredibly annoying, since I can see the names and icons of other open windows behind it.  This doesn't happen with any of the other window manager choices in MATE tweak.

Edit:  The suggested question is asking about the menubar in GNOME, while I'm asking about the title bar of a single window in MATE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable the dynamic transparency effect of the dock while maximizing a window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012328/how-to-disable-the-dynamic-transparency-effect-of-the-dock-while-maximizing-a-wi)

Comment: @abu_bua & reviewers, this question is about MATE, so the dupe target is not applicable

Comment: Please specify Ubuntu version and names of "some themes". Screenshot will be useful too.